# MS Access Syntax error

Tags: ms-access, vba

here is my code:

```
Text22 = DLookup("[Program_No]", "1_Supportive_Housing", "[Program_Name] = '" & Replace([Me.Program_Name], "'", "''") & "' And [BudgetYear] = " & [Me.BudgetYear])
```

I am not sure what is wrong with it, but it keeps giving me the following error:

> Can't find the field | in your expression

I have been trying to get rid of this error but nothing works.

OnKeyPress, this event triggers. As the user writes, it should be able to lookup the value in the table and assign it to text22.

Comment: Ish you have asked the same question or a variety of this same question over and over again. Why not put some of the knowledge you should have gained at this stage to use, rather than constantly posting questions on syntax errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to reference to form fields [Me.Program_Name] & [Me.BudgetYear], but Access tries to find fields with exactly this name, including "Me." prefix. Try to remove brackets at all, or use Me.[Program_Name] and Me.[BudgetYear] instead.

Comment: also, if you are meaning to refer to text boxes on the form, I would be inclined to call them something different than the field name in the table, to avoid any conflicts from that